# When a check is checked, a button is shown

Tags: arrays, reactjs, use-state, use-reducer

I'm using React and I have a list, and each item in the list with a check.

And I want that when there is at least one check in true, a button is shown (it is to delete all the checks).

[image]

---

[image]

I am using `useReducer()` to store the list.

This is my code, but it doesn't work.

```
const init = () => {
    return JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('todos')) || [];
}

const [todos, dispatch] = useReducer(todoReducer, [], init)
const [todoDelete, setTodoDelete] = useState(0)
useEffect(() => {       
        localStorage.setItem('todos', JSON.stringify(todos));
 
        todos.map(todo => {
            todo.check ? setTodoDelete(todoDelete+1) : setTodoDelete(todoDelete-1);
        })
    }, [todos])

returm (

   code...
   {
     (todoDelete!==0) 
                && <button
                    className='btn btn-danger btn-sm h-50' onClick={handleDeleteChecked}>
                    Delete
                </button> 
   }
)
```

What interests me is that when there is more than one check, a button is added, otherwise it is removed. How do i do it?

Answer (score 0):

Change this

```
            todo.check ? setTodoDelete(todoDelete+1) : setTodoDelete(todoDelete-1);
```

To this

```
            todo.check ?? setTodoDelete(prev => prev+1);
```